# Get variables from run?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a PHP script that calls a bash screen using exec and passes some variables via `-f=` and `-d=`

I am just wondering how can I access these in bash? For example I would call

`scaleImage.sh -f=filename -d=directoryname`

And I want to get those variables in scaleImage.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the script you can access those strings via positional parameters. For example:

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

would output

```
-f=filename
-d=directoryname
```

You could use brace expansion or word splitting to break those apart.

See also the section on `getopts` in `man bash` for another way to process options and arguments. Your command line would probably need to look like this if you use `getopts`:

```
scaleImage.sh -f filename -d directoryname
```